# GLFW 3 and VS2012 unresolved external symbol __ultod3

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glfw

Im trying to build a very simple  piece of code to no avail:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>  
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>  

int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
}
```

Please note that i have linked (statically) the glew ,glfw and opengl32 libraries. I have also included the proper include and lib directories in my project properties. On build i am getting the following:

```
**Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __dtoul3  C:\OpenGLWinconsole\glfw3.lib(win32_time.obj)   OpenGLWinconsole**

**Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __ultod3  C:\OpenGLWinconsole\glfw3.lib(win32_time.obj)   OpenGLWinconsole**

**Error 3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   C:\OpenGLWinconsole\Release\OpenGLWinconsole.exe    OpenGLWinconsole**
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't link the libraries correctly!

Comment: I would not consider this a duplicate. This question is specifically about GLFW, the binary download of which contains calls to symbols __dtoul3 & __ultod3 (integer casts). These apparently are missing on some systems. The solution here is to compile GLFW yourself using CMAKE. [Instructions here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html).

Comment: (Also remember that the Visual C++ 2012 generator is called Visual Studio 11 in CMake!)